# Java Springboot - google mail - no longer working as an email service

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail

I am working on a java springboot application locally - and the email service used to be working about a year ago - but I think because of security processes my codebase is no longer working.

I am unsure how to get this re-implemented again with my old googlemail test account -- and I am cautious about the issues trying to implement a mail server once I host the site live.

"I searched the web and primary recommendation was to turn on "Allow less secure applications" on the account, but Google is no longer allows it." --- this link has similar information.

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/184502839/sending-email-via-java-application?hl=en

and its recommended to check out - "create&use app passwords"?
[https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#:~:text=to%2520your%2520data.-,sign%2520in%2520with%2520app%2520passwords,-Tip%253A%2520App%2520Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#:%7E:text=to%2520your%2520data.-,sign%2520in%2520with%2520app%2520passwords,-Tip%253A%2520App%2520Passwords)

-- I have not seen this option on the account - and even if an app/password thing is done -where and how would I implement the app password in the current code?

research

https://forum.katalon.com/t/email-sending-via-gmail-doesnt-work-since-may-30-2022/65957/4

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
package com.rom.service;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import freemarker.cache.ClassTemplateLoader;
import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;


import org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateUtils;
import freemarker.template.Configuration;


public class SendEmailSSL {

    private String hostUrl = "http://localhost:9000";
    private String emailFrom= "ra*******@gmail.com";
    private String emailCompany = "raxxx";

    //@Autowired
    //private Configuration fmConfiguration;

    public SendEmailSSL() {
    }

    public void sendEmail(String template, BasicDBObject model) throws Exception{

        final String username = "ra****@gmail.com";
        final String password = "R*******!";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            String subject = "Welcome";
            switch (template) {
                case "register":
                    subject = "Welcome to xxx";
                    break;
                case "forgot":
                    subject = "We have reset your password";
                    break;
            }

            Message mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom, emailCompany));
            mimeMessage.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse((String) model.get("email"))
            );
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

            //image path
            model.put("imgPath", hostUrl + "/emails/_"+template+"/images/");
            mimeMessage.setContent(geContentFromTemplate(template, model),"text/html");
            Transport.send(mimeMessage);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String geContentFromTemplate(String template, BasicDBObject model) {
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

        Configuration fmConfiguration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        ClassTemplateLoader loader = new ClassTemplateLoader(
                new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23).getClass(), "/templates");
        fmConfiguration.setTemplateLoader(loader);
        fmConfiguration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        fmConfiguration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        try {
            content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils
                    .processTemplateIntoString(fmConfiguration.getTemplate(  template +"-template.html"), model));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }

}
```

---

27th April 2023

I am still struggling with this -- I've added the gmail account to a two way sign on -- and then app passwords becomes an available option
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDELkdvqSz8

[image]

I've changed this to the password in my java application - but still get an error

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
```

[image]

Comment: You have to create a App Password in your account then copy generated password from them and paste it in your variable like `final String password = "WPRTY UFNNR 25YRO 44REDF";`

Comment: where is the link to this dashboard to create an App password -- so instead of the standard email password - I use this generated app password instead?

Comment: I followed this - and changed to the app password - should have no spaces they say -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDELkdvqSz8 -- but this still does not work -- I get a error like this -- javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)